# Is the shell permitted to optimize out useless terminating commands?

Tags: shell, command, posix, standard

If a shell is asked to perform a probably useless (*or partially useless*) command known to terminate, such as `cat hugeregularfile.txt > /dev/null`, can it skip that command's execution (*or execute a cheaper equivalent, say,* `touch -a hugeregularfile.txt`)?

More generally, is the shell similar to C compilers in that it may perform any transformation on the source code, so long as the externally observable behaviour is [*as-if* the abstract machine evaluated it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718262/what-exactly-is-the-as-if-rule)

**EDIT**

Nota Bene: My question as originally posed had a title that asked whether the shell is *permitted* to do these optimizations, not whether it should or even whether implementations that can do them exist. I'm interested in the theory more than the practice, although both are welcome.

Comment: No, the shell isn't as _smart_ as modern compilers.  In fact, it's rather dumb.  It wouldn't optimize any useless code.

Comment: Guessing what the user's intention is is not something the shell should do. The user could be trying to do almost anything with that command, optimising it out would be the wrong thing to do, even if it was possible.

Comment: No matter saying that if the file was a device then `cat`ting it makes a big difference. The shell can get to know that the file is a device, but it need not be reliable.

Comment: `cat`ting a file to /dev/null isn't always useless. Perhaps they want a (not a very good) way to benchmark disk reads.

Comment: _permitted_ by whom? I can certainly write a shell that outputs `"yes I can do that"` for any command that you enter. I do not need to ask the permission to anybody for doing that. However, if I do write such a shell, I suspect nobody will use it, just like I would avoid a shell that doesn't do what I ask it to do.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas C compilers don't need to "ask permission from someone" to optimize their compiled programs; There is an _as-if_ rule in the C standard which permits them to do so. The POSIX standard appears to have standardized at least one shell (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html), as well as numerous other utilities (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/wc.html for `wc`, for instance). But to the best of my knowledge POSIX doesn't take a position on shell optimization; Or does it?

Comment: Optimisation is improving performance with shortcuts without affecting functionality. As long as the functionality is guaranteed, I can't see POSIX objecting. Your proposed optimisation would break [the cat spec though](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) though. There are specific wordings in the POSIX spec that are there to accommodate the type of optimisation done by `ksh`. Like they don't say _separate process_ but _subshell environment_ to allow fork-saving optimisations.

Comment: I used that exact command recently to test NFS transfer speeds.  If the shell had optimized it out, I would've been quite annoyed.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No, that would be a bad idea.

`cat hugeregularfile.txt > /dev/null` and `touch -a hugeregularfile.txt` are not the same. `cat` will read the whole file, even if you redirect the output to `/dev/null`. And reading the whole file might be exactly what you want. For example in order to cache it so that later reads will be significantly faster. The shell can't know your intention.

Similarly, a C compiler will never optimize out reading a file, even if you don't look at the stuff you read.

Comment: You raise a good point, but C also possesses the `volatile` keyword (to ensure that apparently-useless reads and writes are done regardless, and in the order specified), and in C the standardized library function `fread()` only performs the read part of this work, not the write part, and so understandably cannot be optimized. On the other hand, the shell _can_ see all that is about to happen; It executes a complete command at a time, so I was wondering if in its analysis thereof it is permitted to determine that the command is being evaluated only for its side-effects, and act accordingly.

Comment: @Iwillnotexist: Every useful command (except arguably `true` and `false`) has potential side effects, and the side effects are almost always the point of invoking the command.  The shell couldn't know those side effects in advance (for external programs like `cat`) without solving the Halting Problem.  So it rightly doesn't try, and assumes you meant what you said.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist No, the shell can't see all that is about to happen. It has no idea about `cat`. In fact, `cat` could do anything from formatting your hard drive to downloading the Internet.

Comment: "Unix was not designed to stop its users from doing stupid things, as that would also stop them from doing clever things." – Doug Gwyn

Comment: @cHao And even `true` and `false` set `$?`.

Comment: As @scai pointed out above, executables are not like language keywords: `cat` and `/dev/null` have typical meanings but they aren't _guaranteed_ to behave that way. To perform optimizations while guaranteeing no change to expected behaviour, the optimization could only be allowed involve constructs implemented within the shell itself and not things found in the execution environment... no matter how intuitive their names might seem.

Answer (score 20):

No, since `/dev/null` is just a name, which could be used for any other device or for a file other than what "normally" is a data sink.

So a shell (or any other program) has no idea, based on the name, whether the **file** it is writing to is doing something "for real" with the data. There are AFAIK also no system calls the shell program can make, to determine that e.g. the file descriptor is actually not doing anything.

Your comparison with optimising away code in a C program does not work, as a shell does not have the total overview that a C compiler has over a piece of source code. A shell doesn't know enough about `/dev/null` to optimize your example away, more like a C compiler doesn't know enough about code in a function call it dynamically links to, to not make the call.

Comment: As it turns out, ksh93 will treat `/dev/null` specially, sometimes. A builtin that has its stdout directed to `/dev/null`, e.g `echo foo >/dev/null`, will not result in any writes being done to `/dev/null`. It doesn't do anything special if it's invoking a non-builtin command (such as `cat file >/dev/null`).

Comment: Matter of fact, `cat` could also be something else. Anything else in fact.

Comment: Actually `/dev/null` is one of the very few [standardized paths](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap10.html), along with `/dev/tty`, `/dev/console`, `/tmp`, `/dev/` and `/`.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Actually `cat` _is_ a ksh93 builtin (not enabled unless you put `/opt/ast/bin` before `/bin` (or wherever any `cat` is available) in `$PATH`). And yes, though `cat file > /dev/null` with that builtin does `read` the content of `file`, it does _not_ write it to /dev/null (though it opens and fstats it).

Answer (score 15):

It will not optimise out running commands (and you've already received a number of fine answers telling you why it should not), but it may optimise out forks, pipe/socketpairs, reads in some cases.  The kind of optimisations it may do:

- With some modern shells, the last command in a script can be executed in the process of the shell unless some `trap`s have been set. For instance in `sh -c ls`, most  `sh` implementations (`bash`, `mksh`, `ksh`, `zsh`, [`yash`](http://yash.sourceforge.jp/index.html.en), some versions of `ash`) won't fork a process to run `ls`.
- in `ksh93`, command substitution will not create a pipe or fork a process until an external command is called (`$(echo foo)` for instance will expand to `foo` without a pipe/socketpair or fork).
- the `read` built-in of some shells (`bash`, AT&T `ksh`) will not do single-byte reads if they detect stdin is seekable (in which case they will do large reads and seek back to the end of what they are meant to read).

Comment: I like this answer, but it's unclear whether this is original reason, or whether the info is taken from some reference (which I'd like to delve into)

Comment: @yoniYalovitsky, that's _original reason_. `ksh93` is the shell leading the way on the _optimisation_ front as its aim is/was to be seen as being on par with programming languages like `perl`. So you can have a look at `ksh` documentation, code (good luck) and mailing list for further info.

Comment: @stephane You imply that `sh -c` will just exec `ls`?

Comment: @HenkLangeveld, yes, you can verify that with `sh -c 'ps -p "$$"'` which will give you `ps` and not `sh` with those `sh` implementations, or with strace/truss/tusc...

Comment: The difference between `ksh -c 'ps; ps'` and bash -c 'ps;ps' is interesting.  Ksh93 goes further in its optimisation.

Comment: Ha, that's exactly what I'd have done, were I not using android then.

Comment: @HenkLangeveld, depends what implementation of `ksh` we're talking about here. `mksh` behaves like `bash`. That behaviour is mostly meant to optimize things like `system("some command")`. Note that there's a side effect of that optimisation when it comes to the exit status of processes terminated by a signal (in some shells). `ksh93` used to have a _bug_ in that it was doing the optimisation even when traps were set.

Answer (score 7):

When seeing `cat hugeregularfile.txt > /dev/null`, the shell is not allowed to believe that the action is useless — `cat` is not part of the shell and could do anything at all in theory, and also in practice.

For example, the user may have renamed the executable `rm` to `cat`, and suddenly the line performs externally observable behavior, i.e., removing the file.

The user may have compiled a version of `cat` that goes into an infinite loop, thus the shell cannot assume that it is 'known to terminate' as you suggest.

Someone may have installed a version of `cat` that works as intended, but with an extra side effect of installing a rootkit if it's ever run with adequate privileges — again, the shell should duly execute it.

Comment: Actually, `mksh` does in fact optimize `V=$(cat file)` by making it a builtin. So the shell may optimize it out, but not *transform* it to just a `touch -a`.

Comment: @SteveSchnepp, `cat` *is* a builtin in `mksh`, but that builtin resorts to the system's `cat` if passed any option, which is why with GNU `cat`, `mksh -c 'cat /dev/null --help'` doesn't yield the same result as `bash -c 'cat /dev/null --help'`, but `mksh -c 'cat --help /dev/null'` does give you the same as `bash -c 'cat --help /dev/null'` (as `mksh` cat builtin parses options the POSIX way, while GNU cat parses them the GNU way).

Comment: In bash and ksh93, the `V=$(cat file)` can be optimised with `V=$(< file)`.  This speeds up things even without a builtin `cat`.